# Alter field inside fieldset

Tags: webforms

I have created form using Drupal 8 Webform.I have created fieldset and fields.But i couldn't add or alter fields inside fieldset using hook_form_alter.I can add fields outside of fieldset using form alter.How can i alter fields inside fieldset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer. In order to alter Drupal 8 webform we can use code like this

```
$form['elements']['field_name']['#title'] = t('Your Name');
```

I think same method can follow to alter other field attribute.